# Custom Radio Buttons: How to uncheck? (Checkbox Hack)

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I created some custom checkboxes which work great:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwxXar

I tried to do the same with radio buttons. But if one radio button is active and I click another one, the **unchecking does not work**:

➤ https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQLdxd

**Custom Radio Buttons CSS Code**

```
.radio  {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.radio input[type="radio"] {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.radio label {margin-left: 32px;}

.radio label:before,
.radio label:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.radio label:before {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    top: 4px;
    width: 20px;
}

.radio label:after {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 12px;
    left: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 9px;
    width: 12px;
}

.radio input:checked ~ label:after {opacity: 1;}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff, inset 0 0 0 0 #fff, inset 0 0 0 16px #fff;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**Custom Radio Buttons HTMLCode**

```
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio">
    <label>Radio Button 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio">
    <label>Radio Button 2</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio">
    <label>Radio Button 3</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio">
    <label>Radio Button 4</label>
</div>
```

Does anyone of the CSS Super Heros have an idea, why the radio buttons are not working?

Comment: you have to specify the name of the radios : name="radios", the same name for all the radio of the group

Comment: They need a `name` attribute (same name on all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to specify the name of the radios : name="radios", the same name for all the radio of the group

```css
.radio  {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.radio input[type="radio"] {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.radio label {margin-left: 32px;}

.radio label:before,
.radio label:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.radio label:before {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    top: 4px;
    width: 20px;
}

.radio label:after {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 12px;
    left: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 9px;
    width: 12px;
}

.radio input:checked ~ label:after {opacity: 1;}


input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff, inset 0 0 0 0 #fff, inset 0 0 0 16px #fff;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio" name="radios">
    <label>Radio Button 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio" name="radios">
    <label>Radio Button 2</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio" name="radios">
    <label>Radio Button 3</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio" name="radios">
    <label>Radio Button 4</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your CSS. The only thing that you need to take care in case of radio is, radio buttons always works in group. So you have to give them name (`name attribute`)

```
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio" name="rb1">
    <label>Radio Button 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio" name="rb1">
    <label>Radio Button 2</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio" name="rb1">
    <label>Radio Button 3</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <input value="" type="radio" name="rb1">
    <label>Radio Button 4</label>
</div>
```